# Show a path from $a$ to $b$ is homotopic to path from $a$ to $b$ passing through $c$ in path-connected space.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, path-connected

Let $a,b,c \in X$ some path-connected space. Show a path from $a$ to $b$ is homotopic to path from $a$ to $b$ passing through $c$ in path-connected space.

My attempt:
Let $\gamma_0$ be a path from $a$ to $b$ let $\gamma_1$ be a path from $a$ to $c$ and let $\gamma_2$ be a path from $c$ to $b$. Then let $\gamma$ be the product of paths $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$. I.e.,

$$\gamma(t):=\begin{cases} 
      \gamma_1(2t) & t \in [0,\frac{1}{2}] \\
      \gamma_2(2t-1)& t \in [\frac{1}{2},1]
\end{cases}$$

Then can I define a homotopy from $\gamma_0$ to $\gamma$ via

$$H(s,t):= \begin{cases} 
      \gamma_0(2s,t) & s \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]\\
      \gamma(2s-1,t) & s \in [\frac{1}{2},1] 
   \end{cases}
$$

or do I need to break up the intervals more? Thanks in advance for any tips or hints, I'm fairly new to alg top. Also any text recommendations for alg top for dummies type? We're using the last half of Munkres together with the classical Hatcher.

Comment: Can you just run a little whisker from $a$ to $c$ and back before starting the travel to $b$?  If you run from $a$ to $c$ and then back by the same path (in reverse) that little loop will be null.

Comment: @Randall I see what your saying then that compose with the $a$ to $b$ one will be the $a$ to $b$ one as the $a$ to $c$ and back is null. But I wanted to explicitly find a homotopy. For the reverse path you mean $(1-t)$ right?

Comment: Well, you can write it all out, but it's cleaner to make use of results you already have.  You can define the path I suggest as something like $\sigma * \sigma^{-1} * \gamma$ where $\gamma$ is your original path from $a$ to $b$ and $\sigma$ runs from $a$ to $c$.  It is likely that previous results about the path product gives that this is homotopic to $\gamma$.

Comment: @Randall I am about to type a solution using your idea let me know if it works!

Comment: a downvote without cricitisim is worthless.

Comment: Your post does not say that you want to write the homotopy explicitly, as your comment does. But even then, the suggestion of @Randall is the way to go: write your homotopy by breaking it up into a homotopy-concatenation of simpler homotopies.

Comment: got it! thanks! @LeeMosher. makes so much sense, I was overcomplicating things.

Comment: If the paths using $c$ are arbitrary, there’s no reason to expect the two paths to be homotopic. Imagine curves in a torus, where the path through $c$ wraps an extra time around one of the generators of the fundamental group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $X$ is path-connected, any two points can be adjoined via a path. Let $a,b \in X$. Define $\gamma(t)$ as
$$\gamma:[0,1] \to X$$
such that
$$\gamma(0)=a, \gamma(1)=b.$$
Let $c \in X$ and define
$$\sigma:[0,1] \to X$$
such that
$$\sigma(0)=a, \sigma(1)=c.$$
Then if we define
$$\sigma^{-1}:=\sigma(1-t)$$
then $\sigma^{-1}$ goes from $c$ back to $a$ thus $\sigma \star \sigma^{-1}$ is the constant path, based at $a$, denoted $e_a(t).$
Then
$$(\sigma \star \sigma^{-1} \star \gamma)(t) \simeq e_s(t) \gamma(t).$$
is a path from $a$ to $b$ passing through $c$.
Thus
$$(\sigma \star \sigma^{-1} \star \gamma)(t) \simeq \gamma(t).$$
Thus the two are homotopic.

Comment: This is a bit backwards.  Your argument should start with $\gamma$, which dictates $a$ and $b$.  Then, choose a point $c$.  Then, choose a path $\sigma$ thanks to path connectedness.  Then continue....

Comment: @Randall how about now

Comment: You use "$=$" in places where you probably want to mean "homotopic".

Comment: your right I should be using $\simeq$ @Thorgott

Comment: small nit pick: $\sigma \star \sigma^{-1}$ is not the constant path, but is homotopic to it.